# Images not showing on Magento Front Page

Tags: php, image, magento

I can see all the images across other pages, just on the home page those thumbnails not appearing, that is the php code I have got and how I am calling them. Default images are showing without any problem. I have already tested many solutions from forums...etc

> $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
>   ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'short_description'), 'inner')
>   ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id));
>
> if($_productCollection->count()): ?>

Calling images:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(80, 110); ?>" height="105" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to print: 
`var_dump($_product->getId())` and check if it throws id or not.
Also try to change the addAttributeToSelect() as

```
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
```

Let me know if that works.

Thanks

Comment: for the ID print I have got string(1) "3" and for ->addAttributeToSelect('*') it's all working, could you tell me why my method was wrong...?

Comment: You didn't select `thumbmail` attribute which was used to output the image. Basically you need to add it to the array in `addAttributeToSelect`